# I can see the object's field variable in the console but cannot access it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can see the object's field variable in the console but cannot access it by going `objectName.fieldVariableName`

```
var ob = jQuery.get("file.txt");
console.log("This is the resulting object");
console.log(ob);
console.log("This is the responseText");
console.log(ob.responseText);
```

When I attempt to access the response text in shows it as being undefined. However I can see the proper response text when I print the whole object. How do I access the responseText field variable?

[image: This is the output for my code]

Comment: Check the examples on how to use the callback function to retrieve data: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) is an asynchronous method, you need to provide a *callback function* that will be invoked once the request is successful:

```
var ob = jQuery.get("file.txt", function(responseText)
{
    console.log("This is a jqXHR object");
    console.log(ob);
    console.log("This is the responseText");
    console.log(responseText);
});
```

jQuery calls the callback function with the response data as the first argument (`responseText` in the above code).

The reason why you do see the `responseText` in the console is probably because by the time you're expanding the object details, the request has been successful and the `reponseText` field is set.

Also, please note that `ob` is *not* the resulting object but an [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object.

Comment: I tried running this code and it still prints undefined

Comment: I think `ob` on line 4 should be `res`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to use a callback function to handle the `success` event of your `get` request.

```
$.get("file.txt", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

When you execute it in the console, the request has completed and the object is populated. However, in your code snippet, the request has not completed by the time this is executed.

See [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for more information.

Comment: I tried running this code and it still prints undefined